# Uncaught SyntaxError: Javascript Module

Tags: javascript, function, module

Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

I have created a new .js file where I imported previous functions from main .js file.
I imported it all from one direction so I thought the problem is not found. I have tried to add a attribute **type** with value **module**, it appeared me this problem: --
**Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “.” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.**

This is the index.js file sourcing in index.html which contains all functions

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

This is the products.js file calling into products.html which is importing into it functions

```
<script src="products.js"></script>
```

```
import { checkRegex, addAnimation, increaseByHeight, timeout } from "./index";

window.onload = () => {
    const watch = document.querySelector('.watch')
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

    timeout(3000, setInterval(() => {
        items.forEach((item, idx) => {
            addAnimation(item, 'animated', 1)
        })
    }, 500))
}
```

So i need to prevent the problem which is happening while importing the functions.

Comment: Hi there, Im curious, did you use any framework or are you just using the html and js file on their own?

Comment: That is simple HTML and JS

Comment: as per the docs, have you tried adding type="module" to your tag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Yes have tried, it returns another Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “.” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

Comment: Do you have a bundler like webpack setup? you migth want to look into that in order to succesfully use modules https://webpack.js.org/ or try scafolding a project that has a module bundles like create-react-app

Comment: Nope I did not have webpack and I do want to use it as its original